# Were can I find Ubuntu-for-Android HCL?

Tags: hardware, android, compatibility, smartphone, ubuntu-for-android

I am choosing an android device and would like to choose one known to be capable of running [Ubuntu-for-Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android) without problems. Is there a page where I can find a list of compatible devices?

Comment: Have you tried this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.ubuntuinstall ?

Comment: As far as I understand this is an Android application, @kantu. I haven't got any Android devices yet - I am just choosing.

Comment: By HCL you mean a Hardware Compatibility List, right?

Comment: Indeed, @Mitch.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your best bet is to search around and see what devices other people have installed ubuntu onto. Also, you can possibly get in contact with each of those people and inquire them about what problems they experienced. Learn from those who tried it before you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an HCL, but here are the system requirements according to Canonical:

A phone needs the following requirements:

- Dual-core 1 GHz CPU
- Video acceleration: shared kernel driver with associated X driver;
  OpenGL, ES/EGL
- Storage: 2 GB for OS disk image
- HDMI: video-out with secondary framebuffer device
- USB host mode
- 512 MB RAM

Comment: But I have no idea of what does "shared kernel driver" mean and doubt gadgets vendors specify this in catalogues... And, wait, does Android use X?

Comment: Means they share the same driver.